# Sitecron jobs not starting after upgrading to 3.4.0

Tags: sitecron

We have an issue with the Sitecron module. We updated it from 3.2.0 to 3.4.0 since jobs are not firing in the Azure Web Apps. The tasks are running fine locally, though.
In the Sitecore logs, there are no errors. We see the list of jobs loaded, as expected:

```
14588 15:25:13 INFO  Initialize SiteCron: 3.4.0.0
14588 15:25:14 INFO  Loading SiteCron Jobs
14588 15:25:14 INFO  SiteCron - Job Not Loaded - Job Disabled: Job Source: DATABASE - Import Ocean Insight Data Type: xxxx.Feature.InfoHub.Services.OceanInsightsOrderImportJob, xxxx.Feature.InfoHub Cron Expression: 0 0 11-15 ? * * * - Job ItemId:{26D67966-B9BF-445D-9D8D-C0F6BA777042}
14588 15:25:14 INFO  SiteCron - Job Loaded - Job Source: DATABASE - Import Contracts From Azure - Type: xxxx.Feature.InfoHub.Services.ImportContractJob, xxxx.Feature.InfoHub USING Cron Expression: 0 30 10 1/1 * ? * Parameters:  - Job ItemId:{47BE2C1F-9C84-41A5-8C62-735109C14D70}
14588 15:25:14 INFO  SiteCron - Job Loaded - Job Source: DATABASE - Import Orders From Azure - Type: xxxx.Feature.InfoHub.Services.ImportOrderJob, xxxx.Feature.InfoHub USING Cron Expression: 0 30 10 1/1 * ? * Parameters:  - Job ItemId:{B5B41CB4-4AB1-472A-B23A-7CF6BEA7CEB2}
```

But that's all, we don't get the additional lines when a task is executed, as we did before with 3.2.0 or local with the current version:

```
DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1 13:00:00 INFO  SiteCron - Job 1f20ac14-f531-45a7-bcb6-04cd24905158 in group DEFAULT is about to be executed
DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1 13:08:01 INFO  SiteCron - Job 1f20ac14-f531-45a7-bcb6-04cd24905158 in group DEFAULT was executed in 481.8663805. (ItemID: {26D67966-B9BF-445D-9D8D-C0F6BA777042} Archive:False)
DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1 13:08:02 INFO  SiteCron - Ignoring Saved Handler due to stats update.
```

No difference in triggering the jobs manually: the temp item is created, but never run, and stays in the content tree until it's cleaned up on the next initialization:

[image]

With no luck, I tried to copy all the DLLs and config files straight from the package to the azure web app. Also, reinstalling the package makes no difference.

These tasks are critical for the client, and we are currently blocked. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

PS: Sitecore 10.0.0, on Azure PaaS

Comment: Did you do anything else together with Sitecron upgrade? Or Sitecron upgrade was the only change?

Comment: Well, yes, but not related to this functionality. The weird point here is that it works perfectly on local dev, but not running on Azure Web App

Comment: Has it worked on Azure with 3.2? Can you download all the Sitecron binaries from Azure and compare them with those on local?

Comment: Yes, it was working with 3.2. Yes, the binaries are now the ones for 3.4. I manually uploaded them, as well as reinstalling the package in Azure

Comment: Did you enable this file on your PaaS instance. PLEASE NOTE: the file is missing a closing <log4net>. You have to update it manually with the App Service Editor.
https://github.com/akshaysura/Sitecron/blob/master/Code/Sitecron/App_Config/Include/Z.SiteCron/zSiteCron.Azure.config.disabled

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue in SiteCron 3.4 around compatibility with Sitecore 9.2+, please upgrade to SiteCron 3.6+

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But there is some version numbering issue I think? Both the latest `master` on GitHub as well as the DLL file version of the NuGet package labeled 3.6 still show 3.4 in their `AssemblyInfo.cs` and are showing the same behavior as OP describes. So quite possibly Sergi and I are working with what should be the version 3.6 you're referring to.

Comment: I'll admit I haven't used the nuget package, I built it from source

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same behavior and found that this is introduced with SiteCron's upgrade from Quartz.NET version 2.6.2 to 3.2.4.

I've forked the project and made a version with Quartz.NET downgraded back to 2.6.2. Be aware that this changes the `IJob` interface back to having a `void Execute()` rather than the `Task Execute()` from Quartz.NET 3.x.

You can download this downgraded version [from my GitHub](https://github.com/asontu/Sitecron/tree/master/Package).

The bug-report to make SiteCron with Quartz.NET 3.x work reliably is [on the original GitHub](https://github.com/akshaysura/Sitecron/issues/31) of Akshay Sura.

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same issue explained by you for Sitecore 10.2 on-prem. For us upgrading `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll` from `version 4.700.19.46124` to `version 4.700.20.21406` fixed the issue. All Sitecron jobs are now running fine.

Using `Sitecron version 3.4.0.0` and `Quartz version 3.2.4.0` from the package. Thanks to my teammates Jothi and Parvathi for figuring this out.