# SiteCron 3.4 doesn't fire jobs

Tags: sitecron

We're seeing the same issue as described in [this question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29792/sitecron-jobs-not-starting-after-upgrading-to-3-4-0).

SiteCron version 3.4 simply does not fire the jobs you schedule, whether that's through a cron-expression, a specific DateTime or by right-clicking and choosing Execute SiteCron Job Now!

We've been seeing this issue for a long time, with Sitecore versions 9.2 and up at least. So far the solution was "install an old SiteCron version and presto" but with Sitecore 10.2 this is no longer an option because Sitecore 10.2 works with .NET 4.8 and this old SiteCron version does not.

When comparing the contents of the working version package we used to use and the latest from [GitHub](https://github.com/akshaysura/Sitecron/tree/master/Package) I noticed that these lines have been added since:

```xml
<!-- If using an Dedicated Publishing instance then by default run SiteCron jobs on the DP Server - set to false to run on CM-->
<setting name="UsePublishingInstanceAsPrimaryServer" value="true" />

<!-- Setting to enable disable Execute Now context menu -->
<setting name="SiteCron.EnableExecuteNow" value="true" />
```

This should tell you something of how old the working version is, and as well I noticed the default is to run on a dedicated publishing instance. We do not have this (XP0 on-Premise) so I have set this to `false`, but this does not solve the issue.

As well I have checked out the Repo and build the latest `master` and placed those DLL's in the `\bin` folder, this also did not change the behavior.

SiteCron logs don't say anything is amiss, but Jobs simply never get fired to actually run.

Any insights or guidance about where to look much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the question that I mention is very similar, hence why I mention it. That question does not have an answer and is about a different infrastructure and does not include the attempts at solving the issue that my OP includes.

Comment: You should raise the issue here https://github.com/akshaysura/Sitecron/issues. Also try SiteCron 3.6.

Comment: issue raised: https://github.com/akshaysura/Sitecron/issues/31